# Microsoft visual studio 2013 ultimate doesn't open

Tags: visual-studio-2013

The vs 2013 is not getting open. It pops up with a message "Cannot run when setup is in progress". I didn't make any configuration change. 
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try rebooting your pc, after the reboot it'll still continue some setup. Wait for it to complete. Then launch it again!

Comment: I rebooted it yesterday and still it says the same thing.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio installs many other tools along with the application. So try uninstalling it and check the list of installed programs from control panel to see if all the installed tools of Visual Studio are uninstalled, if not uninstall them and the Visual studio too, and then re-install it. Also sometimes the installation needs a service pack 1. So see for it too.

Answer (score 19):

This just happened to me as well. I had three instances of Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate open and when I tried to launch another as Admin, I got the same error, and still got the error after closing all instances and trying again.

I checked task manager and saw a process called "Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (KB30002339) (32 bit)". I previously had Visual Studio 2012 on the machine but I didn't think this would affect 2013 starting. However, after I killed that and tried starting VS 2013 as admin, it was working fine.

Comment: True that, and also sometimes just like installing microsoft office, it shows up some error due to some other versions of the same software present! SO WE NEED TO MAKE SURE WE UNINSTALL ALL OF THOSE BEFORE MOVING FORWARD!

Comment: I had the exact same issue "Cannot run when setup is in progress" and killed that process to get up and running again quickly. Life-saver, thanks!

Comment: So generally, I probably wouldn't recommend keeping around multiple versions of software. However, in many cases, it is a business necessity to keep different versions of the IDE for different projects. Especially for a consultant trading projects back and forth with their respective owners, it's not uncommon to have parallel installations of Visual Studio 2010, 2012, and 2013. Given, Microsoft is fairly confident in the compatibility of projects from 2012 to 2013, but I've seen an issue or two.

Comment: I had to show processes from all users, but there it was.  Very timely solution for a Sunday evening.  Thank you.

Comment: for me it's VS12-KB2932965.exe

Answer (score 3):

To follow on from [@FLGMwt's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27431855/4316831), I was having the same issue. It seems it's quite common according to this article: [Microsoft Ships New Botched Update: KB3002339 Failing to Install](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Microsoft-Ships-New-Botched-Update-KB3002339-Failing-to-Install-467024.shtml)

I fixed this by first ending the task "Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (KB30002339) (32 bit)", then downloading the [KB3002339](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/3002339/) update from Microsoft and running it manually: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/3002339/

Finally, I checked for Windows Updates and this one was no longer showing. Visual Studio now starts without issue.

You could skip manually installing the update by ignoring it in Windows Update.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the above, I did some looking at Task Manager etc. on my Windows 7 machine and saw there was the Trusted Installer running, but no Visual-Studio-2013-specific process.
After browsing the web for fifteen minutes I was able to start up VS2013 without any issue.

I would strongly recommend waiting for at least this length of time before you begin killing processes that may be configuring the software.

Comment: I noticed a couple of Visual Studio related programs in Task Manager (you have to look in the Description column in Windows 7 to find them). Since I have a slow computer they took a while to finish.

Answer (score 1):

Check for vs_community.exe running in your Windows Task Manager. For me, that was the problem. Downloading it manually and installing fixed the problem for me...

Comment: I had two vs_community.exe processes running even after a reboot. Ended them and VS started up properly the next time. Thanks!

Comment: Found the real reason there were instances of vs_community.exe running. One of the VS2015 Azure SDK installs triggered an install of VS2013 in the background. Found VS2013 in Add/Remove Programs and uninstalled it. No more vs_community.exe process anymore. Thanks for pointing me in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue happened on Windows 10 Preview and resolved by stopping the vs update 4 installation process as suggested here. Just noting here for Win10 Preview.